# Field inside of a Field

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to put a field (field_names) inside of the body of the node.

I read that you could do something like:

```
<?php print render($content['field_names']); ?>
```

The above code does not work for me, and just does nothing. Do I need to declare some variable beforehand, or do something else to make the field display? (yes I do have PHP enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you do is use [Token filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) instead of depending on PHP in fields. Tokens look like [node:field_names], and can help you achieve putting one field value inside another.

The php module depends on [bad judgement](http://drupal.org/project/bad_judgement) for a reason, so I will skip trying to help you hurt yourself.